# Crystal Reports Data Formatting Issue

Tags: crystal-reports, format, multicol

I inherited a report where when you run it, the data will be divided into two columns and four rows on one page. I am wanting to change the format so it displays like a basic report where it's just rows listed straight down on the page. The report is below. I am using Crystal Reports 2008 version 12.3.

Report Design:

[image: Report View]

Report Preview:

[image: Example of Report]

Answer (score 0):

- Right click in the gutter of the Details section and choose Section Expert...
- Clear the `Format with Multiple Columns` checkbox

[image]